# AFNetworking not uploading image

Tags: ios, image, file-upload, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to upload an image via `AFnetworking`. I am able to get the image url, and it does contact my server. However, it won't upload. The file upload folder is empty and when I get back my JSON response, it is "null"

```
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];


ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
// Request to save the image to camera roll
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"url %@", assetURL);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:assetURL];
        NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/image.jpg"];
        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        [self uploadPhoto:path];
       // NSLog(path);
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }  
}];

}
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": self.targetid};
        NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:file];
       [manager POST:@"http:/****/uploadpics.php" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
       [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

image url looks like this:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/FFCAE923-1115-4209-AB39-D9D1ACEB9CB7/Documents/yourLocalImage.png
```

I can't seem to figure out what am I doing wrong.. The script is fine because it works for android just as it is supposed to...

PHP:

```
$name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])){
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES ['filename']         ['name'])) {
     Echo  $foname;
 } else {

  }
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your upload code names the file `image` but your script seems to expect `filename`. I haven't done any php for a while but I think they should match.

There is another method which allows you to specify more details about the part that you're appending to the form data so you probably need that to set the appropriate names.

Comment: in php or Obj C?.. my head hurts from all these languages =(.. I am not sure if they should match .. i think filename is is appendPartWithFileURL ... will post it as http post files file name.. could be wrong but ..

Comment: Change the obj-c. Use Charles proxy to see what is actually sent.

Comment: @Wain,I actually narrowed it down with a check on the AFNetworking.. I am getting the following:   b] Append part failed with error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Expected URL to be a file URL" UserInfo=0x146429d0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=Expected URL to be a file URL  apparently the location of my image can't be parsed as an NSURL. but its int the var/folder, isnt that ok? other wise do you know how i can put it in the file:/// directory?

Comment: Looks ok. Did you log the URL? Is it actually nil for some reason?

Comment: @Wain no the url is not nil the url is: /var/mobile/Applications/FFCAE923-1115-4209-AB39-D9D1ACEB9CB7/Documents/yourLocalImage.png  but I log it before converting it into a NSURL. I am going to try to log it as NSURL see if it comes up the same.

Comment: @Wain when i log the nsurl absolueString i get the following :    /var/mobile/Applications/1BCB875E-8782-4117-A5DE-CD2C889C874D/Documents/image.jpg

Comment: So is there actually a file at that URL?

Comment: i assume? i am taking a picture/getting from photo gallery @Wain, I posted that code ...

Comment: @wain added image picker method on top

Comment: Check the save. You may need to add a short delay before the asset data is actually available.

Comment: @Wain, it seems to exists ( i checked) is there a way i can save it to file:/// scheme because from the afnetworking docs that is what it seems to want as a file  uri. not in my /var/documents/folder

Comment: You only don't see the file:// because you are logging the absolute string, you are creating the file URL correctly by the looks do it. Looking at your code on a new day I think your upload is running before the image save block runs. It should be in a different method and called after the image save.

Comment: @Dnaso : i am also getting the same error, can you please tell me how do you fix this problem.